# Is it possible to export Map Service to cache or to raster

Tags: arcgis-server, arccatalog, map-service

I've added The server under GIS Servers  in ArcCatalog. At that server i have Map Service of an orthophoto. is it possible to export that that Map Service to raster or to cache ?